# Learning C# and ASP.NET MVC for a Django/Pylons programmer

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, django, pylons

We have a project coming down the line that's likely going to be in ASP.NET of some sort.  I really hope this means ASP.NET MVC :)

I've created a SOAP web service and a small website in ASP.NET (non-MVC) before, so I'm familiar with the bare basics of C#, ASP.NET, and LINQ (except templates still confuse me significantly).

I am however a rather advanced Python programmer, and I've had a ton of experience in Django and Pylons.  What's the best way to translate this knowledge to ASP.NET?

I'm especially interested in anything that involves the latest versions of .NET, and in *best practices* for .NET, Visual Studio, etc.

Comment: @Charles hehe you beat me to it... I had just seen that discussion on meta about these and was going to remove whatever weird tag I put on here :)

Comment: Funnily enough, I saw that discussion *after* I edited the tag out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing Django will put you in a good position to use ASP.NET MVC - you'll already know about the roles of Models and Views etc.

Python is generally a higher level language than C# so you might find that it can be less powerful to use. On the whole I'd say there isn't much between them though.

The best advice I could give would be to read [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-3rd/dp/1430234040) (Steve Sanderson). This book goes beyond simply teaching the reader about the features of the framework but clearly demonstrates them in context and gives clear examples of what could be considered 'best practice' (subjective, but I largely agree with the techniques he advocates).

I'm actually going the inverse at the moment. I've been using ASP.NET MVC for a couple of years but am moving towards Django for some upcoming projects.

Comment: I also highly recommend the Pro ASP.NET MVC book from Sanderson, I feel it's one of the best books out there.

Comment: If is not ASP.net and you are in hurry I highly recommend the Matthew MacDonald book http://www.amazon.com/ASP-NET-2010-Experts-Voice-NET/dp/1430225297 and if you have less time, really you can just watch the asp.net/learn series of videos and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of PluralSight training. As a supplement to the Sanderson book, not a replacement for.

But for $29/month you won't find better training materials. You can watch ASP.Net MVC courses, C# courses and many other things.

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/